# Modular exponentiation in Assembly x86 using a large base, exponent and modulus (i.e. 512 bits)

Tags: assembly, x86, rsa, primes, 32-bit

I want to generate random RSA primes in Assembly x86. This requires handling large numbers, i.e. 512 bits long. The Miller-Rabin primality test makes use of modular exponentiation, for which the base, exponent and modulus can be the same size as the prime. The problem is that algorithms for calculating the modular exponent still require to take the modulus, which is very big. Which method can be used to calculate this modulus in Assembly?

Calculations which can already be done are multiplying or dividing a large number by a 32-bit number and adding, subtracting and comparing two big numbers.

EDIT:
I found an algorithm to perform division between two large integers. An implementation is given at https://skanthak.homepage.t-online.de/division.html. A more in-depth explanation is given at https://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-iv.html

Comment: Have you looked at https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division like `mpz_mod` for two bigint inputs? (GMP's license is GPL, so I guess don't look if you want code you can use in something incompatible.) The implementation https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpz/mod.c involves `mpz_tdiv_r` which in turn uses `mpn_tdiv_qr`.  The low-level MPN functions are hand-written in asm.  Or there's `mpn_sec_powm` which directly does modular exponentiation. https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions .  Or `mpn_sec_div_r` does modulo.

Comment: Hrm, maybe not all of those have x86-64 hand-written asm directly; https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64 doesn't have filenames that obviously match those functions.  Anyway, if you can use or copy from GMP, look in its source for where those functions are defined and the asm building-blocks they use.

Comment: Usually Montgomery multiplication is used to avoid taking the modulus too often.  You still have to do it every once in a while though.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your suggestions

Comment: The other trick to know is [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  Computing x^n naively would take n multiplications, but with the squaring algorithm it's only O(log n).